# Array String can't be printed out properly

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

i have a string var, give it an example

```
String s = "just\nan\nexample";
```

i want to split that string into string array by using line space(\n) as delimiter, so the output string array will look like

```
String[] array = [just, an, example];
```

so then i tried this code

```
String[] array = s.split("\n");
System.out.println(array);
```

it gave me this output in the console

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@691aca
```

what's going on? am i using this method wrong?

EDIT: Okay, it's answered.. this is one of the answer

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(array));
```

but this make me questioned about something, i also have another string array which i put on the value from a txt file using bufferedreader loop and it can printed out array list seamlessly without using "java.util.Arrays.toString(array)"

but why when i use an array which i value i put on manually (as above) or get from another variable, i can't get it printed out properly without using "java.util.Arrays.toString(array)"?

Comment: @Boris No, I was too fast. So I did not lie I just was wrong.

Comment: arrays do not have toString methods built in

Comment: There's also [this duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-an-array). And probably a hundred others.

Comment: Use `java.util.Arrays.toString(array)`

Comment: i'm sorry if this is duplicate, but i want ask something. i also have another string array which i put on the value from a txt file using bufferedreader loop and it can printed out array list seamlessly without using "java.util.Arrays.toString(array)"

but why when i use an array which i value i put on manually (as above) or get from another variable, i can't get it printed out properly without using "java.util.Arrays.toString(array)"?

Comment: You say _array list seamlessly_; so you mean it's an `ArrayList`? Then you have your answer.

Comment: oh i see, so if it's array type, it can't use println function properly without java.util.Arrays.toString(array).. thanks

Comment: The thing is array itself is an object, but despite other objects, it has no toString() method, which you may override to have a string presentation. And Arrays.toString() simply iterates throught all objects in your array and add it to StringBuffer, and finally you have stringBuffer.toString().

Answer (score 0):

That's because your printing the address of the array. Try looping through the array and get each element like this:

```
String[] array = s.split("\n");
for (String str : array) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```